# How to exclude more than one div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

How to exclude more divs from this code than just one:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#about"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like I couldn't exclude even a single div from your code. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I don't know how to add more elements to this line :  not([href="#about"])')

Comment: `'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#about"],[href="#somethingelse"])'` ???  `How to exclude more divs` But your code is targeting anchors. So what exactly is your question???

Comment: `a:not([href="#about"])` try this.

Comment: How are "divs" involved? You're selecting an anchor ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add item as comma seperated values like `:not([href="#about"], [href="#home"])`.

Bu there are other ways for this like the following.

```
$('a[href*="#"]').not('[href="#about"],[href="#home"]');
```

Comment: Thank you Rejith R Krishnan!